# Как изменить центр обьекта для правильного вращения?

Tags: unity3d, model, blender

У меня есть 3д обьект который я экспортировал из блендера:
[image: Блендер]

После я закидываю его в юнити, и получаю вот такой центр:

[image: Юнити]

Как можно изменить центр, без костылей?

Comment: Самый простой способ - вложить эту модель в пустой объект и сместить немного вбок. А вращать уже родительский объект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сменить позиционирование с `Pivot` на `Center`.

[image: Изображение]

Comment: Если вы хотите задать вопрос, то вам следует написать комментарий, а если вы даете ответ, то подразумевается, что у вас есть вся информация для этого. По последнему вопросу очевидно, что вам информации недостаточно, вследтсвие этого вам, опять же, возможно, следует написать комментарий. Здесь вы можете прочитать о том, [как дать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Только наоборот для меня сработало, спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @МаксимФисман, ответ был дан, после чего я уточнил автора использовалось ли данное решение. От этого вопроса, суть моего ответа не изменилась, я конкретно указал что и где нажимать в том числе и на скриншоте, я смог дать ответ который помог автору, и голосование против моего ответа это потенциально может не дать возможность другим найти решение схожей проблемы

Comment: Ну ответ-то только один, возможность никуда не пропадёт, а вот вопрос вы правильно удалили: его все же стоит задавать в комментариях. А уже потом писать ответ. После получения ответа на вопрос. А иначе, как видели уже было -2. Сейчас к ответу нет никаких претензий и я меняю голос против на голос за!

Comment: @МаксимФисман, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помог. Только начало работать стало, когда поставил Pivot.